# Performing statistical test on every possible file combination in a folder

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a folder with about 100 csv files.  I want to use a two sampled  Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on every possible file combination.  I can do this manually like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import scipy as sp

df=pd.read_csv(r'file1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv(r'file2.csv')
sp.stats.ks_2samp(df, df2)
```

but I don't want to manually assign all the variables.  Is there a way to iterate through the files and compare all the possible combinations using the statistical test?

Comment: Yes, it's called a "nested loop".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to get the cartesian product of a list of filenames with itself.

[Cartesian product of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)

In your implementation, you should have a list of all the filenames in a list, and then call

```
itertools.product(files, files)
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for `itertools.product` it mentions that it is the same as

```
((x,y) for x in A for y in B)
```

Comment: sounds just like what I am looking for, I will read the docs about it, thanks.